# looping over two fields of a big table

Tags: python

I have a table in form of array of tuples. It has 500,000 rows and each row has 25 fields. Assuming fields one and two are x and y of coordinates, for each (x,y) I want to loop over all the rows with that (x,y).

I can't think of an efficient way of doing this.

Another point is that although there are many rows, number of unique x's are around 50.

```
all_x= set([table[i][0] for i in range(len(table))])  #len(all_x) is around 50
```

Anyway, I can't even think of a way to loop over rows with the same (x,y) without looping over the whole table multiple times.

**simplified sample data**

7 rows of 3 fields each. 
[(0,0, 5), (0,0, 10), (1,5, 3), (1,3 ,4) ,(1,5, 10), (2,4, 30), (1,5, 30)]

I want to be able to separate that into [(0,0, 5), (0,0, 10)] and [(1,5, 3),(1,5, 10),(1,5, 30)] and [(1,3 ,4)] and [(2,4, 30)]

Comment: Can you show a simplified example of what your data looks like?

Comment: I added one in the question.

Comment: Great, thanks. I think I got the gist of what the data looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [(0,0, 5), (0,0, 10), (1,5, 3), (1,3 ,4) ,(1,5, 10), (2,4, 30), (1,5, 30)]
a = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0:2])
[list(group) for key, group in groupby(a, lambda x: x[0:2])]
```

Output

```
[[(0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 10)],
[(1, 3, 4)],
[(1, 5, 3), (1, 5, 10), (1, 5, 30)],
[(2, 4, 30)]]
```

Comment: A typo :) it was supposed to be the sorted list `a`.

Comment: I like the way you think Cyber. Thanks.